# Prove that $||x - y|| =r$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let {$x_n$}, {$y_n$}$\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be sequences such that $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to y$ and $||y_n - x|| < r < ||x_n-y||$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $||x - y|| =r$.

My attempt:$r<||x_n-y|| = ||x_n-y+y_n-y_n|| \leq ||x_n-y_n||+||y_n-y||$. Applying limit, we have $r \leq \lim   ||x_n-y_n||$. (From here, can I conclude that $||x-y|| \geq r$?) And I'm stuck in this part. Any hints, please?

Comment: You might reconsider doing $$ r < ||x_n-y|| \leq ||x_n-x|| + ||x-y||$$ In other words, it seems more convenient to apply the triangle inequality with the vector $x$, not $y_n$.

Comment: Why not just use continuity of norm and squeeze Lemma @Michael ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch It looks like MathGurl wants to use $||x_n-x||\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Michael Ok I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$||y_n-x||<r<||x_n-y||$, so by using the limit you get:

$lim||y_n-x||\leq r \leq lim||x_n-y|| \Rightarrow $

$||lim(y_n-x)||\leq r \leq ||lim(x_n-y)|| \Rightarrow $

$||y-x|| \leq r \leq ||x-y||$. So $r$ has to be equal to $||y-x||$.

(We change $<$ into $\leq$ because when you take the limit in an open set you can end up on the boundary)

(You can put the limit inside the norm because the norm function is continues)

Answer (score 2):

Let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.
$$
r< d(x_n,y)\leq d(x_n, x)+d(x,y)\to d(x,y)
$$
as $n\to \infty$. Therefore, $r\leq d(x,y)$. Similarly,
$$
r>d(y_n,x)\geq d(x,y)-d(y,y_n)\to d(x,y),
$$
So $r\geq d(x,y)$. The proof is now completed.